# Matplotlib widgets: Change axes or figure upon button push; make slideshow

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-widget

I would like to create a matplotlib widget that changes the data and axes. It would be great to go even farther and change out a set of subplots.

I've tried modifying:
[matplotlib display only one graph of a set of 10 like a slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731102/matplotlib-display-only-one-graph-of-a-set-of-10-like-a-slideshow)

[Python Matplotlib: change the displayed figure interactively using a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181051/python-matplotlib-change-the-displayed-figure-interactively-using-a-widget)

But both of these answers change the data not the axes or subplots.

I want to pre generate many plots with all sorts of things like pcolormesh, polygons, colorbars, scatter plots, legends, text and annotations. And swap them out on the push of a button or slide bar.

Comment: Would a PyQt application be an option?

Comment: Yes it very much would. What I'm writing is in Qt. Pop up figures is a bonus feature I'm adding that is not flushed out yet so I was trying to cut corners. However if there is an easy way to embed figures in a Qt window I'd love that. In fact I'm going to begin looking at that -- thanks for the idea.

Comment: There are several tutorials on the web and a few posts on SE, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465861/803359 . Usually I do not need the toolbar, so I use a simple widget and make it similar to this example https://gist.github.com/pklaus/3e16982d952969eb8a9a Then add any type of sliders and buttons to modify the plots.